# Android: Activity Lifecycle listener from a static class

Tags: android, android-activity, addeventlistener

I have a single activity app and a static class.

And I want the class to know when the activity status is changed as in onPause onResume event.

I'm passing the activity context to the class but I can't find a way to make it call a function when the status changes.

The activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    MyStaticClass.setup(this, ...);
}
```

the class code:

```
public class MyStaticClass
{
    public static void setup(Context context, ...)
    ...
    // Code for status events

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check on [OnPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) , [OnResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) functions??